# In Magento 1.8, every time I visit a Product page my cart gets empty

Tags: php, magento, web, e-commerce, magento-1.8

I have a magento site using 1.8 version but I am facing severe kind of issue that whenever I visit a product page my previous cart history gets empty.

Does anyone have any idea, is there any quick fix for that by some configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Changing caching setting in app/etc/local.xml. change it session_save variable from file to db and and check it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried changing "files" to "db" in session_save variable but that didn't worked :(

Comment: which browser are using? check browser cookies.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome, what to check in cookies?

Comment: I can see cookies, local storage and session storage etc. for my domain in browser. The only thing I see is that session storage option for my domain in my browser is empty. Is that something wrong?

Comment: check your form key in app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
Code for form key: <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>

Comment: It is already as <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>

Comment: It works fine for products in a category but when I visit product from a different category my cart automatically gets empty.